# can't access apache via custom port

Tags: apache-2.2, port, httpd

I have configured apache to Listen on the port 80 and 4986

I can access it on virtualhost on port 80
but can't access it on port 4986

I have tried `lsof -i:4986` :

```
apache2 26669 www-data    6u  IPv6 46697578      0t0  TCP *:4986 (LISTEN)
apache2 26670 www-data    6u  IPv6 46697578      0t0  TCP *:4986 (LISTEN)
apache2 26739 www-data    6u  IPv6 46697578      0t0  TCP *:4986 (LISTEN)
apache2 26741 www-data    6u  IPv6 46697578      0t0  TCP *:4986 (LISTEN)
apache2 26742 www-data    6u  IPv6 46697578      0t0  TCP *:4986 (LISTEN)
apache2 26837 www-data    6u  IPv6 46697578      0t0  TCP *:4986 (LISTEN)
apache2 26939 www-data    6u  IPv6 46697578      0t0  TCP *:4986 (LISTEN)
apache2 26940 www-data    6u  IPv6 46697578      0t0  TCP *:4986 (LISTEN)
apache2 26941 www-data    6u  IPv6 46697578      0t0  TCP *:4986 (LISTEN)
apache2 26952 www-data    6u  IPv6 46697578      0t0  TCP *:4986 (LISTEN)
```

the port is listened

but when I'm trying `nmap -v -A localhost`

```
Scanning localhost (127.0.0.1) [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 110/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 143/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 993/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 53/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 995/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 25/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 1723/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 21/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 10000/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 9091/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 6502/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 6969/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 8333/tcp on 127.0.0.1
```

the port isn't discovered

I have also to add this on my iptables :

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4986 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 4986 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 4986 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 4986 -j ACCEPT
```

but not working

any idea of what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

It appears Apache is listening on port 4986 on IPv6 only (unless you suppressed the output).

You also append IPTables rules to the existing ones so if there was a drop rule before that you wont be able to access it.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

`nmap` only scans the most common ports by default; 4986 isn't one of them.

run `nmap -p 4986 localhost` and it should show the open port

Comment: I get that : 4986/tcp closed unknown

how can I fix it ?

Comment: See the other answer too...

Comment: nothing on iptable will block this port

Comment: What is/are your `listen` lines in your httpd.conf file?

Comment: NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:4986
Listen *:4986